# C++ coroutine's return_void's and return_value's return type

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

### `return_void`

consider the coroutine's `ReturnObject` below and note the comments before the method `ReturnObject::promise_type::return_void` :

```
struct ReturnObject {
        struct promise_type {
            int val_{23};
            ReturnObject get_return_object() {
                return {std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this)}; 
            }
        std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
        std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        void unhandled_exception() {}

         /*** NOTE THIS ***/
        //void return_void(){  }
        
        /*** AND THIS ***/
        int return_void(){ return 101; }
      };
      
      std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> h_; 
      ReturnObject(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> h):h_{h}{ } 
      operator std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>() const { return h_; } 
};
```

Full code on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/GjE9Kdeqq)

The standard usage on the web and in [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1745r0.pdf) (page 37) suggests that the `return_void` method returns `void` but in gcc 11.2, the `return_void` with `int` return type works as well. Is this correct ? If yes,

1. why does it work with both void  and non-void return type ?
2. what happens to the return value of the `return_void` in the case of non-void return type?

### `return_value`

Similar effects with the method `return_value` can be observed in gcc.
In case of the `return_value`'s returned data, is there a way to access this returned data directly, similar to the normal subroutine/function's returned value ?

Check the code on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/9nfe7vxa7)

### Update:

After @useless's suggestion, I added `[[nodiscard]]` to both `return_void` and `return_value` with non-void return types and enabled `-Wall` flag.

Surprisingly for `return_void` and `return_value` I don't even get a warning with gcc-10.2. Check [here](https://godbolt.org/z/bf6d5s4GP) but gcc-11.2 gives me a warning ([here](https://godbolt.org/z/6ch3jcMsT))

The [compiler warning](https://godbolt.org/z/GMYTj315K) I get for `return_value` with `int` return type looks like below

```
warning: ignoring return value of 'int ReturnObject::promise_type::return_value(int)', declared with attribute 'nodiscard' [-Wunused-result]
   31 |     co_return 7;
      |               ^
<source>:18:27: note: declared here
   18 |         [[nodiscard]] int return_value(int val){return val;}
```

I'm not convinced from the compiler warning that `co_return`s value is being discarded. In reality the return value being discarded is from the method `return_value` but the compiler manages to *shroud it* some how.

Thanks for looking at the post and for suggestions in advance.

Comment: I am not at all a language lawyer, so I cannot tell if this is ill-formed or not. But I am not surprised it compiles. Coroutine support in C++20 works a bit like a preprocessor. The `ReturnObject` must respect an interface. The interface expects  `return_void ()` returning `void` and will just discard the return value if there is one, like `std::sin(1.0);` is a valid C++ statement.

Comment: What happens if you make it `[[nodiscard]] int return_void() { return 101; }`? Currently, I don't see why you'd expect any diagnostic for an ignored return value ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[[stmt.return.coroutine]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/stmt.stmt#stmt.return.coroutine-2) says that the expressions

```
promise_object.return_value(...)
```

and

```
promise_object.return_void()
```

(whichever is used by the `co_return`) shall be of type `void`.

So the return type of either function must be `void` (if it is used by a `co_return`).

MSVC does correctly reject the program:

```
<source>(31): error C7625: The type of a coroutine promise return_value or return_void expression must be void
<source>(18): note: see declaration of 'ReturnObject::promise_type::return_value'
```